# increase size of image and superimpose on transparent image using gd library php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I will get an image from frontend and I want to increase the size of image and copy that image on transparent layout.
I want this because i simply want my image to appear 5 times larger than its original size.

```
$frontimgheight=$frontfeatures['height'];
$frontimgwidth=$frontfeatures['width'];
$frontimgheightnew=$frontimgheight*10;
$frontimgwidthnew=$frontimgwidth*10;

// create transparent layout
$thumbfront = imagecreate($frontimgwidthnew, $frontimgheightnew);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumbfront, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($thumbfront, 0, 0, $color);


$dbfrontimg=imagecreatefrompng("./uploads/".$frontimg);
//$dbbackimg=imagecreatefrompng("./uploads/".$backimg);

imagecopyresized($thumbfront, $dbfrontimg, 0, 0, 0, 0,$frontimgwidthnew, $frontimgheightnew, $frontimgwidth, $frontimgheight);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($thumbfront);
```

Above code simply gives transparent image of 800 x 1000 pixels.

I want my frontend image to be overlapped on transparent layout.

Comment: You can use javascript to change css for width & height

Comment: Thanks but I want to do it on server side using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a library I wrote to do stuff like this: https://github.com/Pamblam/EasyImage

You can resize the image and send it back to the browser in one line:

```
echo EasyImage::Create("./uploads/".$frontimg)
    ->resize($newWidth, $newHeight);
```

You can also do overlays and all kinds of other fancy stuff.